# /dev/mapper/centos-root is at 100% Running CentOs

Tags: linux, centos, disk-usage

we have a VM that host our docker and is currently out of space, I've tried everything on the net and nothing worked out yet, it is so full that I can't even run `yum autremove`

The system type is XFS, and I'm trying to fix this problem without having to remove the partition and create another one. My last solution if I couldn't figure it out is to recover the image from a previous vm version.

I apologize if I have any lack of knowledge in describing this issue and terminology, appreciate any help.

`df -h` shows below

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  24G     0   24G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     24G     0   24G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     24G   18M   24G   1% /run
tmpfs                     24G     0   24G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   39G   39G   20K 100% /
/dev/sda1               1014M  197M  818M  20% /boot
/dev/sdb1                4.0T  275G  3.5T   8% /data/prom_tsdb
/dev/mapper/centos-home   19G   33M   19G   1% /home
tmpfs                    4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/user/0
```

`ls -la` from /dev/mapper

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     120 Feb 27 17:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    3280 Feb 27 17:10 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Feb 27 17:10 centos-home -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Feb 27 17:10 centos-root -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Feb 27 17:10 centos-swap -> ../dm-1
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Feb 27 17:10 control
```

`lsblk -f` outputs this

```
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL           UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1          xfs                         8f8242f9-7c24-4b84-a63e-bdf525dc1050   /boot
├─sda2          LVM2_member                 RoHLXd-Co1E-4UZ5-TeTD-JXx0-ySlG-hPjR7m
│ ├─centos-root xfs                         1329ba02-4819-43a6-b98c-64af4881b353   /
│ ├─centos-swap swap                        f9dfdb0b-1f24-45a9-939b-2ee49ace1461   [SWAP]
│ └─centos-home xfs                         33f236ac-07aa-4552-916c-1eb34d273fab   /home
└─sda3
sdb
└─sdb1          ext4                        c897a887-7bdc-4ba8-b134-f76a3e96efc4   /data/prom_tsdb
sr0             iso9660     CentOS 7 x86_64 2020-11-02-15-15-23-00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `/dev/sda3` might be unused. If it's actually unused and big enough to be useful, you could add it to the `centos` LVM volume group (VG for short), and then use its capacity to extend `/dev/mapper/centos-root`.
Also, if `sda3` is not reusable for some reason, but there is unpartitioned space on the `/dev/sda` disk, now would be a good time to get it into use, by creating a new partition from the unpartitioned space.

To verify, use `lsblk` without the `-f` option, or `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

You might have to clear a little bit of space first, to allow the LVM tools to successfully make their LVM configuration backups before each operation. In many cases, `yum clean all` does that nicely by cleaning the package management caches.

```
yum clean all
pvcreate /dev/sda3
vgextend centos /dev/sda3
lvextend -r -L <new size> /dev/mapper/centos-root
```

All this can be done while `/dev/mapper/centos-root` is mounted and in use.
No reboot required.

If `/dev/sda3` is not big enough and the `sda` disk is fully allocated (check with `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `lsblk` without the `-f` option), then you might have to extend the `sda` virtual disk. How to do it depends on what you are using as a virtualization host. But once you've done that, using the new capacity requires some more steps.

First, install the `cloud-utils-growpart` package, as the `growpart` command in it makes it really easy to extend partitioned virtual disks.

Verify that the VM's operating system recognises the new increased size of the `sda` virtual disk, using `lsblk` or `fdisk -l`. If not, run `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan` and check again.

Now you can extend `sda3` to cover the added space:

```
growpart /dev/sda 3
```

(or if `sda3` is in use by something else, use `fdisk` to create a new partition `sda4`. Verify that `lsblk` sees it; if not, use `partprobe /dev/sda` to rescan.)

If you already added `sda3` to the `centos` volume group, use `pvresize /dev/sda3` to make LVM aware of the larger size of the partition, and then `lvextend` to add the capacity to the filesystem, same as above.

Comment: A million up votes and kudos to you, worked pretty well.